# Does a safe-core-sdk multi-send transaction revert if one of the actions fails?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Am currently using the Gnosis `safe-core-sdk` and `safe-service-client`. Am building out some functionality which batch sends varying amounts of tokens to various addresses using the multi send feature that is part of the SDK.

I have built it out so that I can build a transaction via the core sdk, and then propose it using the `safe-service-client`. At this point, the transaction is visible in the Gnosis Safe official UI, for the vault I have sent it too. It contains all the actions (token transfers) that were specified in the transaction that was proposed.

What am I wondering is, what happens to the transaction if one of the actions/transfers fails? My presumption is that the entire transaction reverts and none of the token transfers are completed, but would be good to confirmation of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultiSend.sol` library requires transactions to be successful, so yeah, if one of the underlying transactions fails, it should revert:

https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/MultiSend.sol#L58-L59

You can test if it reverts by estimating the gas for the transaction beforehand. It won't be able to estimate gas if the transaction is failing.

`safe-core-sdk` should throw an error if the transaction reverted too

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying that.

Is there a way to estimate multi-send transactions? The endpoint is only for single send right? `/v2/safes/{address}/transactions/estimate/`.

Would you have to just loop through each action and get an estimate for each one?

Comment: the transactions are encoded in the ethereum transaction data, so in the end, you have 1 transaction. check how it's encoded in the interface https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/blob/dev/src/logic/safe/transactions/multisend.ts#L12 or you can check tests in safe-contracts repository

Comment: You have to set the `gasPrice`, `baseGas`, and `safeTxGas` as part of creating the multi-send transaction though? Therefore need to hit the estimate endpoint before the transaction is created. If this is the case, then what data do you post for the transaction to the endpoint to get these gas estimates? Or am I missing something :D

Comment: `gasPrice` and `baseGas` are relevant only if you use a relayer/want gas refunds, `safeTxGas` is the available gas limit for the internal transaction, if you use contracts 1.3.0 it's not really required

Comment: Okay so with v1.3.0 of the `safe-core-sdk` I can basically all of those options as part of a multi-send transaction?

The issue I'm having is that v1.3.0 causes this issue https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/139 - which means in the official safe UI, the transaction has 0 for the gas limit, and one for the gas price. The same is true of v1.1.1

Comment: This is a different issue. Usually the gas limit is 0 if the UI can't estimate it and that means the transaction reverts.